# How to split and read raw data into different numpy arrays based on delimeter parameter

Tags: python, numpy

I have a raw data in the following form

```
#######
#######
#col1 #col2 #col3
1       10    100
2       11    150
3       14    155
#######
#######
#######
#######
#col1 #col2 #col3
1       14    100
2       17    180
3       14    155
#######
#######
#######
#######
#col1 #col2 #col3
1       19    156
2       27    130
3       24    152
#######
#######
```

I want to load this data into a NumPy array. When I load this using `numpy.loadtxt` the entire data is being loaded into a single array. Is there an easier way to split this data into different chunks based on the `#######` lines?

Comment: Couldn't you first split the file into separate files, then import them with `numpy.loadtxt`? Additionally, `numpy.loadtxt` itself returns a `ndarray` type, which doesn't seem to suit your multiple arrays output need. You will thus need to work around this.

Comment: That works too, is there any easy way to split these files into small chunks based on the #### lines?

Comment: Is the separator always 4 lines of 7 "#"? Also, what is written in the file beside the data and the separators?

Comment: Hi, yes the separator is always 4 lines of 7 '#'. Except for the first chunk, which starts with two lines of 7#. The file contains several columns of numbers in float. I can upload the actual data file if necessary but is huge.

Comment: Nevermind, the pattern is simply two lines before, two lines after each table. I'm on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be to read the file, split the obtained string at the separators, clean the remaining unnecessary lines and use `numpy.loadtext` on these lists of strings. (As explained in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), lists of strings as parameters in `numpy.loadtext` are treated as lines)

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import List

filename: str = "data_file.txt" # Put your filename here instead

with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    content: str = file.read()

datas: List[str] = content.split(4 * "#######\n")
arrays: List[np.ndarray] = []
for data in datas:
    data_list: List[str] = data.replace("#######\n", "").split("\n")
    arrays.append(np.loadtxt(data_list))
```